# How Vue's event can change const variable is possible?

Tags: vue.js, events, constants

How **Vue's** `event` can change `const` variable is possible?

The 'state' is the primitive `const` variable. Of course, it is impossible to change the value.

error: state ++

However, there is no error when increasing the state through the inline event.

Why is that?

https://codepen.io/quietjun/pen/gOvEjvq?editors=1111

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ko">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>모두의 코딩</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="app">
            <span>{{state}}</span><br />
            <button @click="state++">inline</button><br />
            <button @click="increase">function</button><br />
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

```js
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3"></script>
<script>
    const { createApp } = Vue;

    createApp({
        setup() {
            const state = 1;
            // of course below line is error
            //state++;
            const increase = () => {
                state++;
            };

            return {
                state,
                increase,
            };
        },
    }).mount("#app");
</script>
```

Of course state is not reactive. However, using the developer tool, you can see that the value has changed.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
return {
  state,
  increase,
}
```

is short for

```js
return {
  state: state,
  increase: increase
}
```

In other words, inside `<template>` you don't interact with the `const state` from `<script>`.

You interact with the template context's properties. Think of it as an object created by merging everything that needs to be exposed to the `<template>` (e.g: spread return of `data`, all `computed`, all `methods`, spread return of `setup`, all `props`, etc...)

And you can safely write to an object's property, unless it has been defined as `writeable: false`, which is clearly not the case.

Simple example:

```js
const a = 1;
// a++; => Error: "Uncaught TypeError: Assignment to constant variable"

const b = { 
  a,
  increment() {
    this.a++ //  similar to what you're doing in your handler
  }
};

b.a++;
console.log(b.a); // 2! no error.

b.increment();
console.log(b.a); // 3! no error.
```

Additionally, `@click="expression"` is wrapped in an anonymous function by Vue if `expression` is not callable (akin to `@click="() => { expression; }"`).

---

Side note: In your example, if you want `state` to be reactive you have to declare it as `const state = ref(1)`. Otherwise, even though `state++` will change `state`'s value, it won't trigger a re-render, so it will look like it didn't update, until something else triggers a component re-render and the template value gets updated (overridden).